# Creating a similar table

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create a table similar to the one in the picture below.

I don't use LaTeX often and I am in need of some help.

Any info would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: package `booktabs` is used.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial table to get your started:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Effects of Moderators on the Relationship Between Exposure to Scary TV and Internalizing Responses}
\centering
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c}
  \hline
   &  &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{95\% CI} &  &  \\\cline{4-5}
  Moderator & \textit{k} & Estimate & Lower & Upper & \textit{Test} & \textit{p} \\\cline{1-7}
  \textbf{Study Characteristics} &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
  {Experimental or correlational} & 129 & -0.159 & -0.269 & -0.049 & $\chi^2(1)=8.08$ & .005 \\
  etc. & & & & & \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**yields:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How would I do an indentation (e.g. Child vs. Parent under Responder)?

Comment: There may be a more proper way to do this, but I would just push the text of each cell that needs to be indented with `\hspace`. Swap out the `etc. & ...` row with: `{\hspace{1em} etc.} & & & & & \\ `, and of course it doesn't have to be 1em.

Comment: I don't think you need `\bgroup`/`egreoup` here, as it is within a `table`-environment. Also, the `booktabs`-package could make the table look more alike the example. I would also align many of the numbers, either at `=`-signs, or decimals, using `siunitx`. This of course isn't really done in the example, but there is nothing wrong with improving the look.

Comment: @Runar thanks, I've removed the group ends from the answer now

Answer (score 1):

You can actually improve the quality by using `siunitx`. Here's only some relevant lines, the others will follow the same schemes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable,siunitx,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=raggedright}

\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{Effects of moderators and the relationship between
  exposure to scary TV and internalizing responses}

\small
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-2pt}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  c
  *{3}{ S[table-format=-1.3] }
  c
  r
  @{}
}
\toprule
&&& \multicolumn{2}{c}{95\% CI} && \\
\cmidrule{4-5}
Moderator & $k$ & {Estimate} & {Lower} & {Upper} & \textit{Test} & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{$p$} \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l@{}}{\textbf{Study characteristics}} \\
Experimental or correlational &
  129 & -0.159 & -0.269 & -0.049 & $\chi^2(1)=8.08$ & $.005$ \\
Responder & 129 &&&& $\chi^2(2)=0.14$ & $.056$ \\
\quad child vs.\@ parent &
      & -0.010 & -0.067 &  0.047 & $z=-0.34$ & $.736$ \\
Outcome measure & 129 &&&& $\chi^2(5)=22.39$ & $<.001$ \\
\quad general vs.\@ fear &
      &  0.213 &  0.111 &  0.315 & $z=4.11$ & $<.001$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]